# How to change editor font from within a Visual Studio addin?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-addins

I would like to be able to change the editor font in Visual Studio 2012 by using a keyboard shortcut. As macros have been removed, I understand this leaves only the option of writing an add-in.

So to clarify, I want to write an add-in that sets the editor font to *a single specific font*. I don’t want it to pop up any dialogs, as if it did that, I might as well use Tools → Options.

I already have an add-in that adds a Visual Studio command, so I already know how to do that. I also know how to assign a keyboard shortcut to it, so this question is not about either of those.

What are the commands in the Visual Studio add-in API to change the text editor font?

Comment: The commands weren't specified in the Visual Studio Add-on API documentation?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: No, they weren’t. Furthermore, said documentation was really hard to find, too. (Try googling for “Visual Studio Add-in API documentation” — nothing relevant comes up.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s the answer:

```cs
private void setFont(string fontFamily, int fontSize)
{
    foreach (Property prop in _applicationObject.Properties["FontsAndColors", "TextEditor"])
    {
        if (prop.Name == "FontFamily")
            prop.Value = fontFamily;
        else if (prop.Name == "FontSize")
            prop.Value = fontSize;
    }
}
```

`_applicationObject` is assumed to contain the `DTE2` object for the host environment.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: With a lot of patience.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to Timwi. As a bonus to his answer, the following ones were useful to me to change properties in Tools -> Options:

```cs
_DTE2.Properties["TextEditor", "General"].Item("DetectUTF8WithoutSignature").Value = true;
_DTE2.Properties["Environment", "Documents"].Item("CheckLineEndingsOnLoad").Value = true;
```